# how to retriving textbox data from database table automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, textbox, keypress

when i am writing this code on my textbox for retrieving data from database automatically after writing name in textbox but it does not working...please help me

```
protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT EmployeeID, Weight, Amount FROM Supplier where  EmployeeName=@EmployeeName";
            var DS = new DataSet();
            var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["inventoryConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            var SDA = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, conn);
            SDA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeName", TextBox2.Text);
            try
                {

                  SDA.Fill(DS);

                foreach (DataRow row in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
                {

                  txtboxid.Text = row["EmployeeID"].ToString();
                  txtboxw.Text = row["Weight"].ToString();
                  txtboxam.Text = row["Amount"].ToString();

                 }
                 }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {


                }
        }
```

Comment: What error r u getting, Have u debugged using breakpoint

Comment: I suggest you to use dropdownList with autoComplete function !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using SqlDataReader

```
string selectQuery = "SELECT EmployeeID, Weight, Amount FROM Supplier where  EmployeeName=@EmployeeName";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, conn);
            SqlDataReader dataReader;
            conn.Open();
            dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dataReader != null)
            {
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    //Retrieving data vales from select query in variables
                   txtboxid.Text = dataReader["EmployeeID"].ToString();
                     txtboxw.Text = dataReader["Weight"].ToString();
                     txtboxam.Text = dataReader["Amount"].ToString();


                }
            }
```

Comment: i write this code on this text event...protected void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
i am not using any button in this form ...

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(Connection_String);
SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand(Command, Conn);
Conn.Open();
textBox.Text = Comm1.ExecuteScalar();
Conn.Close();
```

Try

Comment: boss it does not clear to me.....
showing error in executescaler()...it doesn't require any definition...

Comment: while(reader.Read())
        {
put this condition in

 foreach (DataRow row in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
                {

Answer (score 0):

I can only recommend you to use the [AjaxControllToolkit AutoCompleteExtender](http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)